# Downloading zipfile into a temp folder from s3 bucket - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip, temporary-files

I have a folder zip uploaded to an s3 bucket.
I want to extract that zipped folder into a temp folder.
I am using the following code:

```py
import io
from operator import sub
import boto3
import zipfile
import os
import sys
import tempfile 

#Connection to s3
S3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucketname = os.environ.get('Databucket')
bucket = s3.bucket(bucketname)
key = "Data.zip"
cwd = os.getcwd()

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as moduletemp:
    print('Created temporary directory:', moduletemp)

bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketname)
Zip_obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=bucketname, key = key)
zip_buffer = io.BytesIO(Zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer)
zlist = zfile.namelist()
for f in zlist:
    y = zfile.open(f)
    Archname = 'modeltemp' + "/" + f
    x = io.BytesIO(y.read())
    x.save(Archname) # for saving the file into the temp folder created
```

The file is not getting saved properly in the temp folder with the last command:

```py
x.save(Archname)
```

Please suggest how to save the content finally into the temp folder as it is getting extracted.

Note that I am not intending to specifically save it to s3 but just saving it to the temp folder would be fine for now.

Thanks

Comment: the `with TemporaryDirectory` will delete the temporary directory when you leave the context manager scope (IE you create the directory, print that you created it and then delete it ... but later try to use it)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Thanks. Can you explain a bit more please.

Comment: The [io library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) does not show a save() function. You'll probably need to create a file using standard Python `open()` commands and store the contents: [Reading and Writing Files in Python (Guide) – Real Python](https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/)